# Can I edit a WordPress plugin and preserve my changes when the plugin updates?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm mainly interested in adding classes to a few of the containers in one particular plugin - so I can style those elements. I've saved the .php files, and kept notes of the changes, but cannot find a solution (if any) to maybe create a child plugin that will preserve my edits.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not really. That's why plugin authors are encouraged to include hooks for other plugins to customize their behavior.

You could create a [diff file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff) with your changes and use it to try re-applying your changes after an update, but you might run into difficulties if the plugin code changes substantially.

Comment: That's what I thought. We'll attempt to submit a feature request. The mods I made only took a few minutes, just classes for styling specific elements. Thanks - I'm not really a PHP programmer so this is helpful.